# What is the difference between these two systems?

Tags: initial-value-problems, chaos-theory

I have these two models:

[image: systems]

Both show **Temperature vs Time** for 15 different input conditions (i.e. inlet fuel velocity).

**My question is**: what is the difference between these two systems? Is one of them chaotic/non-chaotic? It is evident that the system on the left is independent of initial conditions as all values converge toward the end of the simulation - is that not the definition of non-chaotic dynamics? If so, since the other system "does care" about every change in the initial conditions - is it **more chaotic**?

Just trying to correctly formulate the difference in the underlying system dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't describe either as chaotic. The second one does turn small differences into larger differences, but it does so in a very clear and predictable way.

For example, $a_0 \times 1.01^n$ also results in larger changes for small differences in the value of $a_0$, but in a nice and predictable way.

On the other hand, $x_{n+1} = kx_n(1-x_n)$ is very different, a small difference in the value of $k$ can result in wildly different behavior in the sequence of $x_n$.

Comment: thanks! that is very helpful. Is there a name/term I can use in my work for what you have said: "turn small differences into larger differences" ?

Comment: Also, is it correct to say that the system on the right is "more sensitive to initial conditions" - this is how I ended up talking about chaos... As sensitivity to init cond is big part of chaos description.

Comment: Yeah, "more sensitive to initial conditions" is how I would describe that system.
For chaos, you would want the dynamics to be sensitive to initial conditions. I believe a more precise definition would get quite involved.

Comment: OK. Thanks again! Lastly, do you think the Largest Lyapunov Exponent (LLE) would be an appropriate measure to quantify the difference between the systems' sensitivity to initial conditions (I saw that this is what LLE measures) - although LLE is used mostly in the context of chaos/nonchaos, so just to make sure...

Comment: Or is there another measure altogether that can quantify the difference in sensitivity to initial conditions?